# Can I recover the original image of text after processing by adobe professional OCR?

Tags: pdf, images, adobe-acrobat, ocr

Someone used (probably) Adobe Professional OCR feature to OCR a scanned pdf file. The OCRed result had some errors, and it added the text result back to the text image in the pdf file, covering the actual text image, so I can't tell what the correct one that the text image shows

Can I recover the original image of text after processing by adobe professional OCR? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily list or extract all images from a PDF (or just from a specific page range) using the command line tool `pdfimages`. This tool is available for Linux, Unix, Mac OS X and Windows.

```
 pdfimages -list -f 3 -l 7 my.pdf
```

Above command lists all the images from page 3 (`-f` "first") to page 7 (`-l` "last") without extracting them.

The most recent versions of `pdfimages` do even include additional info, such as width/height dimensions of the image, compression ratio, color space, bit depth, image encoding and resulting resolution as compared to the PDF page's own size:

```
kp@mbp:> pdfimages -list -f 3 -l 7 porsches-a4.pdf
 page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3     0 image    1920  1440  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        20  0   175   175  182K 2.2%
    4     1 image    1920  1440  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        26  0   175   175  130K 1.6%
    5     2 image    1920  1440  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        32  0   175   175 92.1K 1.1%
    6     3 image    1920  1440  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        38  0   175   175  233K 2.9%
    7     4 image    1920  1440  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        44  0   175   175  238K 2.9%
```

To ***extract*** a specific page's images as JPEGs use the `-j` parameter:

```
kp@mbp:> pdfimages -j -f 11 -l 11 porsches-a4.pdf prefix
```

This would extract all images from page 11. Their names would be `prefix-000.jpg`, `prefix-001.jpg`, `prefix-002.jpg` etc.

**NOTE:** Sometimes direct extraction as JPEG isn't possible. `pdfimages` will still extract them, albeit in `PNM` or `PPM` format. You can easily convert these to PNG or JPEG by using ImageMagick's `convert` command:

```
 convert some.ppm some.png
 convert some.pnm some.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

If the images are still present, it is possible to extract them. You could use Photoshop or a tool like this: http://www.somepdf.com/some-pdf-image-extract.html